# Lazy-loading a SQL row upon construction of a Perl Moose object?

Tags: mysql, perl, moose

I'm using Moose to represent objects with persistent data stored in a SQL database.

Given a sample SQL table 'people':

```
id - unsigned int
name - varchar(200)
email - varchar(200)
phone - varchar(200)
```

I would like instantiation

```
my $person = Person->new( id => 123 );
```

to set $person->id to 123, but not yet load the row with id=123 from the SQL table.  However,

```
my $name = $person->name;
```

would lazy-load the entire row from the SQL database, and set the name to $name. Later,

```
my $address = $person->address;
```

would use the already lazy-loaded row, and set the address to $address.

Any recommendations & patterns?

BONUS POINTS for answers that allow elegant subclassing, e.g. Person::Employee having additional attributes such as 'job_title', 'salary', and including how to best store additional subclass attributes in the SQL 'people' table (or multiple tables, maybe 'people_employee'?)

Or if I'm going about this in entirely the wrong way, that'd be good to know too! I'm very aware of ORMs (such as DBIx::Class) but don't really like the api, and also plan to add a fair amount of functionality to the object that doesn't involve the SQL table, and that seems ideal under Moose.

Comment: I know you said you don't like ORMs, but just for reference, [here's a way to get lazy-loaded columns with DBIx::Class](http://blogs.perl.org/users/ovid/2010/07/lazy-database-columns-and-virtual-vertical-partitioning.html).

Comment: Also, having objects where at least some of the attributes are mapped to database columns sounds a lot like you're re-inventing an ORM. [It's easy to store non-db data in DBIx::Class Result classes.](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Manual::FAQ#How-do-I-store-my-own-(non-db)-data-in-my-DBIx::Class-objects?)